# What is the difference between a combinator and a higher order function?

Tags: functional-programming, definition, higher-order-functions, combinators

I have always thought the definition of both of these were functions that take other functions as arguments. I understand the domain of each is different, but what are their defining characteristics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, let me try to kind of derive their defining characteristics from their different domains ;)

First of all, **in their usual context** combinators **are** higher order functions. But as it turns out, context is an important thing to keep in mind when talking about differences of these two terms:

**Higher Order Functions**

When we think of higher order functions, the first thing usually mentioned is "oh, they (also) take at least one function as an argument" (thinking of `fold`, etc)... as if they were something special because of that. Which - depending on context - they are.

*Typical context*: functional programming, haskell, any other (usually typed) language where functions are first class citizens (like when LINQ made C# even more awesome)

*Focus*: let the caller specify/customize some functionality of this function

**Combinators**

Combinators are somewhat special functions, primitive ones **do not even mind** what they are given as arguments (argument type often does not matter at all, so passing functions as arguments is not a problem at all). So can the identity-combinator also be called "higher order function"??? Formally: No, it does not **need** a function as argument! But hold on... in which context would you ever encounter/use combinators (like I, K, etc) instead of just implementing desired functionality "directly"? Answer: Well, in purely functional context!

This is **not** a law or something, but I can really not think of a situation where you would see actual combinators in a context where you suddenly pass pointers, hash-tables, etc. to a combinator... again, you **can** do that, but in such scenarios there should really be a better way than using combinators.

So based on this "weak" law of common sense - that you will work with combinators only in a purely functional context - they **inherently** are higher order functions. What else would you have available to pass as arguments? ;)

Combining combinators (by application only, of course - if you take it seriously) **always** gives new combinators that therefore also are higher order functions, again. Primitive combinators usually just represent some basic behaviour or operation (thinking of S, K, I, Y combinators) that you want to apply to something without using abstractions. But of course the definition of combinators does **not** limit them to that purpose!

*Typical context*: (untyped) lambda calculus, combinatory logic (surprise)

*Focus*: (structurally) combine existing combinators/"building blocks" to something new (e.g. using the Y-combinator to "add recursion" to something that is not recursive, yet)

**Summary**

Yes, as you can see, it might be more of a contextual/philosophical thing or about what you want to express: I would **never** call the K-combinator (definition: `K = \a -> \b -> a`) "higher order function" - although it is very likely that you will never see `K` being called with something else than functions, therefore "making" it a higher order function.

I hope this sort of answered your question - formally they certainly are **not** the same, but their defining characteristics are pretty similar - personally I think of combinators as functions used as higher order functions in their typical context (which usually is somewhere between special an weird).

**EDIT:** I have adjusted my answer a little bit since - as it turned out - it was slightly "biased" by personal experience/imression. :) To get an even better idea about correctly distinguishing combinators from HOFs, read the comments below!

**EDIT2:** Taking a look at [HaskellWiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Combinator) also gives a technical definition for combinators that is pretty far away from HOFs!

Comment: By your definition of HOFs, all functions are HOFs. This is not quite correct, actually. A HOF is a function which necessarily takes a function as one of its arguments. It makes more sense in typed languages.

Comment: oh where exactly do I say that all functions are HOFs? that was definitely **not** my intention :)

Comment: You said "I would never call the K-combinator (definition: K = \a -> \b -> a) "higher order function" - although it is one, since it will not be mad at you for passing functions...". The reason upon which you based that `K` is a HOF entails what I said in the previous comment.

Comment: oooh okay i see! you're absolutely right, that reason is formulated crappy - but i mean you cannot say that K is no HOF, do you? don't get me wrong, i totally agree that my reason is wrong, but... well combinators **always** are HOFs, aren't they? (otherwise also stackoverflow's tag-description for "combinator" is wrong) :D

Comment: aaaaaaand you are wrong in one point: "A HOF is a function which necessarily takes a function as one of its arguments." it may also be a function that just **returns** a function ;) and **that** is done by `K` (yes, i still hope for a better formulation for why K is a HOF)

Comment: No, the tag-description for "combinator" is not precise. A combinator is just a function that combines its arguments using nothing but function-application. There is no restriction on the arguments of a combinator, and thus combinators are not necessarily HOFS, but in practice many of them are. `K` is an example of a combinator which is not an HOF.

Comment: No, that definition (I believe this is the wikipedia def.) of an HOF is also wrong. By this definition every function which takes more than one argument is a HOF, which is obviously wrong. Consider for example curried functions.

Comment: yes, wikipedia also says that but i'm pretty sure that was also how they tought it back in university (hoping they did not just read out wikipedia articles)... but absolutely, in the context of curried functions i would also ignore that part of the definition... hmmm okay this is getting interesting :)

Comment: question: in which context would you ever seriously use/find combinators? i never saw them anywhere else than in purely functional context (or "manually set up" functional context like declaring `delegate D D(D d);` in C# or similar...) soooooo in THAT context there just is nothing else than functions - including church encoded data structures... i mean seriously, in what other context would you ever use the K combinator??? :)

Comment: To be honest, I've never encountered combinators outside of purely-functional languages such as Haskell. And yes, I believe combinators make more sense in these purely-functional contexts.

Comment: **you** do know what you are talking about :D thanks a lot for pointing out my sloppy reasoning! ...will think about different wording ;)

Comment: You're most welcome. Thanks to you for accepting my comments :)